# using jquery accordion collapse only working on one section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

So in my div i have a data-bind which will display multiple headers with content within. I want to use jQuery in order for me to collapse and expand but with what i have currently regardless of what header i am clicking it only collapses and expands the first header.

How can i alter what i have so that it could collapse and expand any header clicked and not just the first one?

```
   <div class="accordion-group elements-by-unit" style="display:none" id="listView"  data-bind="foreach: Types">
            <div class="text_x-large header">
                <span  data-bind="text:Name()"></span> 
                <span class="userCount">(<span data-bind="text:UserCount()"></span>)</span>
                <span class="icon-minus-sign" data-toggle="collapse"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse in" data-bind="template: { name: 'list', foreach: $data.Users }"></div>
        </div>

<script type="text/html" id="list">
    <h3 id="letter" data-bind="text: Letter"></h3>
    <div class="smoke_hover">
        <span class="h2"><small data-bind="text: Name"></small></span>
    </div>
</script>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        (function ($) {
            Views.User.Init({
                url: '@url',
                id:@ViewBag.SectionID,
                roleUser:@ViewBag.UserSettings
                });

            var togglerArr = [];
            var contentArr = [];

            $('.icon-minus-sign').each(function(){
                togglerArr.push($(this));
            });
            $('.collapse').each(function(){
                contentArr.push($(this));
            });

            for (var t = 0; t < togglerArr.length; t++) {
                togglerArr[t][0].dataset.target = "#rUsers-" + t;
            }

            for (var c = 0; c < contentArr.length; c++) {
                contentArr[c][0].id = "#rUsers-" + c;
            }
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

Comment: You only have one div with the `#rUsers` id. Are divs with `.header` and `#rUsers` repeating in outputed html? If so, you'll have to create unique ids for `#rUsers` and add it to the corresponding header as data-target

Comment: @BojanaSekeljic yes they are repeated in my output and whenever i click the header it is only functioning on the first #rUsers ignoring the others.

Comment: check my edited comment above

Comment: @BojanaSekeljic how can i create unique ids since i have them in a foreach loop?

Comment: can you post the loop code?

Comment: @BojanaSekeljic i added the inner loop above

Comment: sorry, i didn't see the data-bind on accordion element, I ll post workaround soon

Comment: @bojanasekeljic thanks a lot :) will be looking forward to it

Answer (score 1):

ID passed in `data-target` of your `span.icon-minus-sign` has to correspond with the ID of the  `div.colapse` that you want to collapse.

Because all your `span.icon-minus-sign` are targeting all the divs outputted (because all of them have the same `#rUsers` id) it is bind to the first element it finds, and that is the first `div#rUsers`.

To go around this, dynamically add IDs, with incrementing numbers would be the best, and add it to both data-target and id. In your case only solution I see is:

**Javascript**

```
var togglerArr = [];
var contentArr = [];

$(".icon-minus-sign").each(function(){
    togglerArr.push($(this));
});
$(".collapse").each(function(){
    contentArr.push($(this));
});


for (var t = 0; t < togglerArr.length; t++) {
     togglerArr[t][0].dataset.target = "#rUsers-" + t;
}

for (var c = 0; c < contentArr.length; c++) {
     contentArr[c][0].id = "#rUsers-" + c;
}
```

And modified html (I removed data-target and coresponding id, as we are setting those in script)

```
<div class="accordion-group elements-by-unit" id="listView" data-bind="foreach: Types">
<div class="text_x-large header">
    <span  data-bind="text:Name()"></span>
    <span class="userCount">(<span data-bind="text:UserCount()"></span>)</span>
    <span class="icon-minus-sign" data-toggle="collapse"></span>
</div>
<div class="collapse in" data-bind="template: { name: 'list', foreach: $data.Users }"></div>
```

Please let me know if it works for you! Also make sure all .js files are called in right order.

Comment: I am trying this out but i noticed in the javascript there is `#rUsers` yet in the html there isn't an id for it - is that how it is supposed to be?

Comment: yes, javascript code is finding all divs with the class `.collapse` and ads id incrementing id to it. if you are using collapsible items on other places on the website, you might want to add more specific selector here, ie. putting the whole thing in the div with the specific id and then targeting it in the javascipt with `$('#specific .icon-minus-sign')`

Comment: I updated my post above with the javascript but i am still not able to get any of the headers to collapse or expand and not sure why

Comment: can you post what is the html output?

Comment: ok, but can you post what is rendered in the browser? are headers and content divs receiving the proper ids? other problem might be that the bootstrap.js is loaded before the view, in that case you might need to inject bootstrap.js as a dependancy

Comment: Yes everything is displayed properly with the icon to click but when i click nothing happens - it doesn't collapse

Comment: then it is definitely the order of scripts loaded, try to modify that

Comment: I believe that i will need to have some sort of `attr` binding to link up with the `#rUsers` - i am still playing around with it

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
$('.header').click(function()
{
    $(this).siblings('.collapse').slideToggle();   
})
```

I used [siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) to find the siblings of the header with class .collapse 
 Also used [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) so you don't have to check if the content is visible or not(automatically slideUp and slideDown)
**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qnj6m/3/)**

Comment: this is doing what i already have. all the headers when clicked collapse or expand the first header only

Comment: Check my update. Even when you have a div inbetween the header and the collapse, it will still collapse. It works on mutiple headers as you see in jsFiddle.